# Как сделать циклическую обработку исключения?

Tags: c++, try-catch

Предположим, есть функция `get_text()`, считывающая данные из потока ввода. При пустом вводе функция генерирует исключение. Как так организовать работу `try` и `catch`, чтобы пользователь имел бесконечное количество попыток ввода? Можно сделать метку перед блоком `try` и переходить по ней из `catch` каждый раз, но решение с применением `goto` не есть хороший стиль, как и бесконечный цикл с `break` после удачного вызова функции. Нет ли других способов зациклить обработку ошибок?

Comment: Не использовать в таких случаях исключения. Использовать коды возврата и проверять их.

Comment: Если неправильный ввод ожидаем, это не исключительная ситуация, согласен с @avp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(true) {
   try{

      :

      break;
   } 
   cahtch(...) {

      :

   }
}
```

Comment: можете вместо бесконечного цикла переменную завести, которая будет вместо break получать значение, которое их цикла выводит

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понимаю, почему вариант с `break` является плохим стилем, но в любом случае способов тут - миллион. Практически любой общий способ организации цикла "удача/неудача" (не относящийся к обработке исключений) подходит

```
bool success = false;
do
  try 
  {
    get_text();
    success = true;
  }
  catch (...)
  {
  }
while (!success);
```

или

```
bool success;
do
  try 
  {
    success = true;
    get_text();
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    success = false;
  }
while (!success);
```

И т.п.

Answer (score 0):

На С++ 11 правда есть ещё такой вариант:

```
while([]{
    try {
        func();
    }
    catch (...) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}) {}
```

но мне он кажется некрасивым, хотя его можно причесать завернув в обёртку из шаблона... ну это уже другая история.

Answer (score 0):

Не усложняйте жизни, пропишите рекурсивную функцию
Приведу пример на шарпе

```
void Request()
{
  try
  {
  choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline());
  }
  catch
  {
  Console.Writeline("Сообщение об ошибке");
  Request();
  }
}
```